# Openfire - Where to see offline Messages

Tags: openfire

i wonder wether it's possible to see stored offline messages of the open fire servers. Is there a way or plugin to see them?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @MarTin did you find anything i also need the same for my iPhone App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is achievable if you enable the "Message Audit Policy" in the Server configuration. Also check out the list of ["Chat and Message Login" plugins](http://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1041) for more comfortable way of doing this.